# Page content overlapping navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having some trouble with some of my bootstrap cards overlapping my navbar. I made sure that none of my positions were absolute and that the z indexes were handled properly, but I still get the same issue. doing padding-top on the body did not give me the result I wanted either. Here are some before and after pictures.

[image: Before Scrolling up]

[image: After Scrolling Up]

```css
#top {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

.topbar {
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #24414e;
  border-left: 2px solid #24414e;
  border-right: 2px solid #24414e;
  border-top: 2px solid #24414e;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #24414e;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  animation-name: greeting;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes greeting {
  0% {
    background: url('https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/751466/screenshots/3360272/hello-3.gif');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/*
    .topbar:hover{
     background:url('https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/751466/screenshots/3360272/hello-3.gif');
     background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
    */

.logo {
  transform: translateY(50%);
  font-family: "Dancing Script";
  color: #ffffff;
}

.holder {
  width: 5%;
  height: 80%;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.out {
  margin-top: 46px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.out:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.menu {
  height: 15%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: #f7ce3e;
}


/*
    .iconbar{
     
     margin-top: 20px;
     margin-right: 20px;
     margin-left:20px;
     height = 
     text-align: center;
     border-left: 2px solid #24414e;
       border-right: 2px solid #24414e;
       border-top: 2px solid #24414e;
       border-bottom: 2px solid #24414e;
    }
    
    */

.icon {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #24414e;
  animation-name: iconSlide;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.txt {
  font-size: 15px;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: #24414e;
}

@keyframes iconSlide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(600%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.icon-1:hover~.txt-1 {
  visibility: visible;
}

.icon-2:hover~.txt-2 {
  visibility: visible;
}

.icon-3:hover~.txt-3 {
  visibility: visible;
}

.icon-4:hover~.txt-4 {
  visibility: visible;
}

.icon-5:hover~.txt-5 {
  visibility: visible;
}

.icon-6:hover~.txt-6 {
  visibility: visible;
}

.icon:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.rest {
  height: 100%;
}

.contacts {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<!---This is for importing bootstrap and the CSS File--->

<head>
  <title>Dashboard</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="templatestyle.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing Script' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!---Nav Bar and Header--->
  <section id="top">

    <!---Header--->
    <div class="container-fluid topbar">
      <h1 class="float-left logo">Example</h1>
      <h5 class="float-right out">log out</h5>
      <img src="blank-person-male.png" alt="profilepic" class="rounded-circle float-right holder"></img>

    </div>

    <!---Nav Bar--->
    <div class="container-fluid menu" id="openMenu">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-tachometer fa-2x icon icon-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h5 class="txt txt-1">Dashboard</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="col-2 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x icon icon-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h5 class="txt txt-2">Profile</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="col-2 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-certificate fa-2x icon icon-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h5 class="txt txt-3">Certificates</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="col-2 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-2x icon icon-4" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h5 class="txt txt-4">Send/Apply</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="col-2 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-cog fa-2x icon icon-5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h5 class="txt txt-5">Settings</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="col-2 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x icon icon-6" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h5 class="txt txt-6">Messages</h5>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </section>

  <section class="rest container-fluid">

    <h2 class="text-center"><u>Dashboard</u></h2>

    <!---Contacts--->
    <h4>Online contacts:</h4>
    <div class="row contacts">


      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">


        <div class="card border-success">
          <div class="card-header">Person 1</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <img src="blank-person-male.png" alt="profilepic" class="card-img-top rounded"></img>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="Button" class="bg-primary rounded mx-auto .text-light">Send Chat</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card border-success">
          <div class="card-header">Person 2</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <img src="blank-person-male.png" alt="profilepic" class="card-img-top rounded"></img>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="Button" class="bg-primary rounded mx-auto .text-light">Send Chat</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card border-success">
          <div class="card-header">Person 3</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <img src="blank-person-male.png" alt="profilepic" class="card-img-top rounded"></img>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="Button" class="bg-primary rounded mx-auto .text-light">Send Chat</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card border-success">
          <div class="card-header">Person 4</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <img src="blank-person-male.png" alt="profilepic" class="card-img-top rounded"></img>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="Button" class="bg-primary rounded mx-auto .text-light">Send Chat</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card border-success">
          <div class="card-header">Person 5</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <img src="blank-person-male.png" alt="profilepic" class="card-img-top rounded"></img>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="Button" class="bg-primary rounded mx-auto .text-light">Send Chat</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card border-success">
          <div class="card-header">Person 6</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <img src="blank-person-male.png" alt="profilepic" class="card-img-top rounded"></img>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="Button" class="bg-primary rounded mx-auto .text-light">Send Chat</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card border-success">
          <div class="card-header">Person 7</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <img src="blank-person-male.png" alt="profilepic" class="card-img-top rounded"></img>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="Button" class="bg-primary rounded mx-auto .text-light">Send Chat</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you don't mind making a fiddle

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple fix, just set your Header `z-index: 2;` and your cards `z-index: 1;`.

I didn't really go over your code but setting the header an higher z-index as the content for sure will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you have given `position:fixed` to the header(`.top`) to fix it at the top with `top:0`, so you must need to give `margin-top` to the section next to it containing classes `class="rest container-fluid"` otherwise it will overlap as it seems with absolute positioned element. 
Setting `margin:top:159px` fix the issue.

Please note that `159px` is top header's height here. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

## Use the `fixed-top` class instead of the `top` CSS code. And add 160px padding-top for the body.

```css
/*
The headers height is 159.5px
*/

body {
  padding-top: 160px;
}
```

---

`fixed-top` removes the `element` that you use it for, from the normal flow of the content, and, hence, the `element` will overlay the other content

To fix the issue, you need to push down the `main` content equal or larger than the height of the `fixed-top` element. You can do so by setting the `padding-top` of the `body` equal or larger than the `fixed-top element's height`. For example, if the `fixed-top element's height` is `72px`, padding-top of body should be, at least, `72px`. If you wish, you can use `relative` units: `padding-top: 4.5rem;` instead of `padding-top: 72px;`.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 72px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="fixed-top bg-light">
  <div>
    <noscript>
      <h1 style="color:#FF0000;">
          This reportFile will not be navigable without Javascript, please enabled Javascript
      </h1>
  </noscript>
    <img srcset="style/songkongheader.png 400w,style/songkongheader-medium.png 200w,style/songkongheader-small.png 100w," sizes="(max-width:800px) 200px,(max-width:600px) 100px,400px" class="mb-2">
  </div>
  <header>
    <h2 class="subheading" title="Start Fixing Songs">
      <a class="mx-2">
          Fix Songs
      </a>
    </h2>
  </header>
</div>
<main class="container-fluid bg-primary bd-">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col py-5">Hello</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

---

This is what both [`bootstrap-3`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) and [`bootstrap-4`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/navbar-fixed/) has done. I recommend you to inspect it yourself.

---

You may find these two link useful.

- [w3schools - How to - fixed menu](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp)
- [teamtreehouse - div hiddne below fixed position navbar](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/div-hidden-below-fixed-position-navbar-clearfix-issues-with-css)

---

#### [A codepen of your work](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dKXZMg)